# Does being a materialist mean that you have to be a hedonist?

Tags: ethics

Materialist as in someone who believe that the universe is experienced by the senses and that's what's real. Hedonist meaning that your goal is to maximize happiness, or reducing suffering.

Comment: Where did you source your definition of materialism? See [here](https://www.philosophybasics.com/branch_materialism.html): "Materialism holds that the only thing that can be truly proven to exist is matter. Thus, according to Materialism, all things are composed of material and all phenomena are the result of material interactions, with no accounting of spirit or consciousness. As well as a general concept in Metaphysics, it is more specifically applied to the mind-body problem in Philosophy of Mind".

Comment: There seems no logical connection either way. You can be a materialist (or physicalist) without being a hedonist, and a hedonist without being a materialist (or physicalist).  It would be helpful to know what assumptions ground the question. Welcome to PSE btw - Geoffrey

Comment: I would agree with @GeoffreyThomas I think it is an immensely simplified version of the language of philosophy to just place the burden of proof on someone like that.

Comment: you might want to read this https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-non-naturalism/ Mackie is the famous "error theorist", and he basis that on something close to what you may mean. mind you, I have no idea what he thinks about 'happiness'

Comment: You could strengthen your question by recognising that 'materialist' and 'materialism' are many-ways ambiguous terms - and that no standard definition or characterisation of 'materialist' fits your explication. I don't mean to be heavy about this. You've asked a question as best you can but you could - and I think should - reformulate the question with a more nuanced and standard specification of 'materialist'. Hope this helps as it's meant to.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. For example, communists are materialists (see [Dialectic materialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectical_materialism)), but they can be hardly called hedonists.

Comment: 'Materialism' is a many-ways ambiguous term. Classical materialism is very roughly the view that the basic constituents of reality are physical or that the whole of reality is physical. Dialectical materialism does not construe materialism in either of these senses or anything like them. Marx's view is 'materialist' in the sense that human history, including human thought and institutions, are (again very roughly) the product of the way in which economic production, distribution and exchange are organised. It's the economic base of society that determines the superstructure of law, morality,&.

Comment: I agree, however, that 'materialism' taken in Marx's sense  (in the rough sense I've sketched or in its full, nuanced statement) does not imply hedonism, a doctrine I've no evidence he ever held.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas I think Leninist offshoot was dealing more directly with physical matter rather than only social phenomena: *Matter is a philosophical category denoting the objective reality which is given to man by his sensations, and which is copied, photographed and reflected by our sensations, while existing independently of them.* See [Materialism and empirion-criticism](https://www.marxists.org/archive/lenin/works/1908/mec/)

Comment: Thank you: I am of course familiar with Lenin's *Materialism and empirio-criticism*. I was answering in the context of the 'dialectical materialism' widely attributed to Marx, though he never used the phrase: it was coined, I believe, by Plekhanov in 1891. I believe that Marx was a materialist only in the sense I indicated in my comment. I do not controvert your view of Lenin, and I much appreciate your taking time to comment on my comment.